# Integral on the intersection of a cone and cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $S$ be the surface formed by intersection of the cone $ z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$. Calculate the following integral over the surface $S$.

$$\iint_S x^2y^2+ y^2z^2+ x^2z^2\,\mathrm dS$$

*My attempt:* The easiest way to parametrize it for me was cylinderical coordinate.The the conditions boils down to $ r \le 2\cos(\theta)$, $z = r$.

Now we have the parametrization $R(t) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), r)$ so the surface element $\mathrm dS$ will be equal to

$$\left|\frac{\partial R}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial R}{\partial \theta}\right| = \sqrt{2} r,$$

since only for $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ the value of $\cos(\theta)$ is non-negative we have to compute
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \int_0^{2\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{2} r^5( 1 + \cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta))\,\mathrm dr\right) \mathrm d\theta,$$
which  isn't much complicated but  to ugly to compute. Does anyone know a better methond resulting in a simpler integral?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick.

The begining is straight forward:

$\sqrt 2\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\cos\theta} r^5(1+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta)\ dr\ d\theta\\
\sqrt 2\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {1}{6} (2\cos\theta)^6(1+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta)\ d\theta\\
\frac {32\sqrt 2}{3}\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos^6\theta + \sin^2\theta\cos^8\theta\ d\theta\\
\frac {32\sqrt 2}{3}\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos^6\theta + \cos^8\theta-\cos^{10}\theta\ d\theta\\
$

Now we have two roads we can go by.  We can say $\cos^2\theta = \frac 12(1 + \cos 2\theta)$ and keep reducing the order and simplifying.  This is what they taught you in Calc II.

The tricky way:
$\cos\theta = \frac {e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}\\
\cos^n\theta = \frac {(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})^n}{2^n} = \frac {e^{in\theta} + {n\choose 1}e^{i(n-2)\theta} + {n\choose 2}e^{i(n-4)\theta} + \cdots +{n\choose n} e^{-in\theta}}{2^n}$

We can then pair $e^{in\theta}$ terms with $e^{-in\theta}$ terms to turn back into $\cos n\theta$ terms.  However, it is not really necessary as $\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos 2n\theta \ d\theta = 0$

This means we just need the constant terms.

$\frac {32\sqrt 2}{3}\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {1}{2^6} {6\choose 3} + \frac {1}{2^8}{8\choose 4} - \frac {1}{2^{10}}{10\choose 5} d\theta$

Comment: Liked the tricky way.Can I also ask for sharing the motivation?

Comment: $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x \implies \cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \text { and } \sin x = \frac {e^{-ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: No I understood the solution I mean how you came up with the solution because using complex numbers for representing cos seems a bit unnatural to me for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is correct and I do not see a much simpler approach than what you have done. Here is an alternate working which simplifies the integrand before evaluating the integral.

We know that for cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \ dS = \sqrt2 \ dx \ dy$

On the surface of the cone, $f(x,y,z) = x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2$

$ = x^2y^2 + z ^2 (x^2+y^2) = x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 $

The projection of the surface in XY-plane is $(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq  1$. If we translate the coordinate system in x direction to the center of the circle, $x = X + 1, y = Y$ and the equation of circle is $X^2+Y^2 \leq 1$.

$f = (X+1)^4 + Y^4 + 3 (X+1)^2 Y^2$

$ = X^4 + 4X^3 + 3X^2Y^2 + 6X^2 + 6XY^2 + 4X + Y^4 + 3Y^2 + 1$

Now we must note that as the region is symmetric to Y-axis, integral of $X^3, XY^2$ and $X$ will be zero as they are odd functions wrt $X$. So,

$f = X^4 + 3X^2Y^2 + Y^4 + 6X^2 + 3Y^2 + 1 = (X^2+Y^2)^2 + X^2Y^2 + 3X^2 + 3(X^2+Y^2) + 1$

Using polar coordinates, the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \sqrt2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (r^5 + 3r^3 + r + 3 r^3 \cos^2\theta + r^5 \cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta) \ dr \ d\theta $

$\displaystyle = \sqrt2 \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{17}{12} + \frac{3}{4} \cos^2\theta + \frac{1}{6} \cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta\right) \ d\theta $

$\displaystyle = \sqrt2 \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{17}{12} + \frac{3}{4} \frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2} + \frac{1}{24} \frac{1 - \cos (4\theta)}{2}\right) \ d\theta $

We know integral of $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\cos(4\theta)$ over $[0,2\pi]$ is zero and that completes the work with a final answer of $\dfrac{29\pi}{4\sqrt2}$